# Интервалы времен с вычетом других интервалов

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from datetime import time

service_duration = time(hour=1)  # сколько занимает времени услуга
intervals = 30  # minutes. здесь может быть любой тип, который удобнее для решения задачи

# рабочее время
times_list = [
    {'start': time(10, 00), 'end': time(16, 00)},
    {'start': time(18, 00), 'end': time(20, 00)}
]

# существующие записи
reservations = [
    # time: время записи
    # end: когда закончится запись (time + duration)
    # duration: сколько времени занимает запись
    {'time': time(12, 00), 'end': time(13, 00), 'duration': time(1, 00)},
    {'time': time(14, 00), 'end': time(15, 00), 'duration': time(1, 00)}
]
```

Необходимо получить список интервалов времен, в которые можно записаться на часовую услугу , учитывая рабочие часы и уже занятое время (из существующих записей). Результат разбить на intervals для записи.

Должно получиться следующее:

```
result = [
    time(10, 00),
    time(10, 30),
    time(11, 00),
    time(13, 00),
    time(15, 00),
    time(18, 00),
    time(18, 30),
    time(19, 00)
]

result: [datetime.time(10, 0), datetime.time(10, 30), datetime.time(11, 0), datetime.time(13, 0), datetime.time(15, 0), datetime.time(18, 0), datetime.time(18, 30), datetime.time(19, 0)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Реализовал универсальную функцию, которая возвращает список с временами для записи.

Для решения разделил на слоты с интервалами по 5 минут. Свободное время помечается, единицей в массиве, занятое соотвественно нулем. Далее заменяются на 0 зарезервированные времена, после чего преобразовывается список в нормальный вид с учетом необходимых интервалов для записи.

```
from datetime import timedelta, datetime, time


def get_result(times_list, reservations, service_duration, interval):
    slots = []
    result = []
    slot_interval = timedelta(minutes=5)

    for idx, time_obj in enumerate(times_list):
        time_start = timedelta(hours=time_obj['start'].hour, minutes=time_obj['start'].minute)
        time_end = timedelta(hours=time_obj['end'].hour, minutes=time_obj['end'].minute)

        while time_end > time_start:
            slots.append(1)
            time_start += slot_interval

        if time_obj is not times_list[-1]:
            next_time = times_list[idx + 1]
            next_start_time = timedelta(hours=next_time['start'].hour, minutes=next_time['start'].minute)
            while next_start_time > time_end:
                slots.append(0)
                time_end += slot_interval

    work_start_time = timedelta(hours=times_list[0]['start'].hour, minutes=times_list[0]['start'].minute)
    for reserve in reservations:
        reserve_start = timedelta(hours=reserve['time'].hour, minutes=reserve['time'].minute)
        reserve_end = timedelta(hours=reserve['end'].hour, minutes=reserve['end'].minute)
        reserve_idx = (reserve_start - work_start_time) // slot_interval
        while reserve_end > reserve_start:
            slots[reserve_idx] = 0
            reserve_start += slot_interval
            reserve_idx += 1

    need_slots = int(service_duration / slot_interval)
    add_pos = int(interval // slot_interval)
    for idx, slot in enumerate(slots):
        if slot is 1:
            sm = sum(slots[idx:min(len(slots), idx + need_slots)])
            if sm >= need_slots:
                if idx % add_pos == 0:
                    result.append((datetime.min + work_start_time + slot_interval * idx).time())

    return result
```

Для получения результата необходимо вызывать функцию get_result() с параметрами:

```
times_list = [
    {'start': time(10, 00), 'end': time(16, 00)},
    {'start': time(18, 00), 'end': time(20, 00)}
]

reservations = [
    # time: время записи
    # end: когда закончится запись
    {'time': time(12, 00), 'end': time(13, 00)},
    {'time': time(14, 00), 'end': time(15, 00)}
]

service_duration = timedelta(hours=1)  # сколько занимает времени услуга
intervals = timedelta(minutes=30)  # интервалы для записи

# вызов функции
work_times = get_result(times_list, reservations, service_duration, intervals)
for time in work_times:
    print(time)

# outputs:
# 10:00:00
# 10:30:00
# 11:00:00
# 13:00:00
# 15:00:00
# 18:00:00
# 18:30:00
# 19:00:00
```